# How to extract the answer from sp.solve?

Tags: python, sympy

When I use sp.solve, I get my answers in two sets of brackets, but I only want the numerical answer. How do I do this?

This is my final answer, I want to get just the number 1.250000, instead of p1: 1.250000.

```
print(sp.solve(max1))
[{p1: 1.25000000000000}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
solution = sp.solve(max1)
solution[0]['p1']
```

The outer bracket is a list, you get the first element with `[0]`
The inner bracket is a dictionary, you get the value by asking for the key `['p1']`

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the dictionary by specifying the symbol for which you are solving. You will still need to extract the answer from the list, though:

```
>> solve(max1, p1)
[1.25000000000000]
>>> _[0]
1.25000000000000
```